# What are more natural ways to say that your test scores are decreasing?

Tags: idiomatic-language

"My marks are decreasing." Does that sound natural?

And when I want to indicate to a more severe decline: "My marks are plummeting."

What are other natural ways to say it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it depends on the type of English you're trying to speak and the level of formality you're trying to achieve.

1. American (US) English speakers would probably use **"grades"** instead of **"marks."** Otherwise, "marks" is fine.  Using "marks" instantly tells an American listener that you're speaking **UK/British English**.  Whether that matters is up to you.
2. "Decreasing" and "plummeting" are fairly **formal** words in most English-speaking dialects.  In my opinion:

   - the most casual forms could be [**"going down"** and **"really going down"**].
   - Another slightly less casual way could be [**"dropping/falling"** and **"sinking"**].
   - If you're in a formal situation (e.g., writing a job application or something), [**"decreasing"** and **"plummetting"**] sound good to me!
3. If you want to really show off, you can use some idiomatic phrases to express the severity of the decline, like "my {marks/grades} are **taking a nose-dive!**" :)

Source: native US English speaker, Bachelor's in linguistics